# Loop Through TD Element in HTML document from inside Frame VBA Excel IE8 Automation

Tags: html, excel, html-table, frame, vba

I am trying to capture Table data inside a particular webpage Frame using Excel VBA.

Unfortunately the website is non-public, so I cannot give access.

Here is a snippet from the END of HTML (showing the LAST cell data) I extracted from Firefox Debugger from the Table I need.

```
<td class="ewrcc s35 b-17"><div class="ewrcv-nw">ExampleValue</div></td>
</tr></tbody></table>
```

I have edited my thread post as @Tim Williams kindly pointed my in the right direction to first set a reference to the Frame inside the webpage (Frame 12)

After setting a reference, I have found all of the Table data using:

```
Set HTMLDoc = ie.document.frames(12).document
Set HTMLTD = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")

For xTD = 0 to HTMLTD.length - 1  

j = Len(HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(xTD).innertext)   

    If j > 0 and j < 50 then

    '''Code here

    debug.print HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(xTD).className
    debug.print HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("TD")(xTD).Innertext

    End If

Next xTD
```

I have produced a spreadsheet and can capture the data in a somewhat cumbersome way by using the Innertext from a static known string ("Oct") and then cycling a count through the number of columns known for each table I am retreiving (2 in this case)

Usually I loop through the Row/Cell .length, but I have found when looping through the TD elements they do not have ROW/CELL objects from the method I am using. I would much prefer this way as it appeared faster, and I could automate the task without prompting a variable to trigger where the table populates.

My question is now: Is there anything I am overlooking? Eg. Can I access the table through the Reference Frame 12 and cycle through Children / Parent etc.? I would really like to reference the Table Object to cycle through the rows & cells if possible

Here is a larger snippet of the last row of a Table, the values I need to extract are labelled "DATA VALUE 1-21":

```
</tr>
<tr class="r46" style="height:15pt;">
<td class="ewrcc s4 b-33"></td>
<td class="ewrcc s23 b-21"><div class="ewrcv-nwl">DATA VALUE 1/21</div>
</td><td class="ewrcc s24 b-21"></td>
<td class="ewrcc s24 b-21"></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 2/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 3/21</div></td>
<td colspan="3" class="ewrcc s23 b-35">
<div class="ewrcv-nwl">DATA VALUE 4/21</div></td>
<td ewrcolumnindex="9" class="ewrcc s24 b-21">
<div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 5/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s23 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nwl">DATA VALUE 6/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s23 b-21"></td>
<td class="ewrcc s23 b-21"></td><td colspan="2" class="ewrcc s23 b-35">
<div class="ewrcv-nwl">DATA VALUE 7/21</div></td>
<td ewrcolumnindex="15" class="ewrcc s34 b-21">
<div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 8/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s25 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 9/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 10/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s24 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 11/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 12/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 13/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 14/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 15/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 16/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 17/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s24 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 18/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 19/21</div></td>
<td class="ewrcc s33 b-24"><div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE 20/21</div>
</td><td class="ewrcc s33 b-35">
<div class="ewrcv-nw">DATA VALUE21/21</div>/td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can get a reference to the frame then `myFrame.document.tables` will give you all of the tables in that frame's document.  When you find the correct table, `myTable.getElementsByTagname("td")` will give you all of the cells in that table (or you can loop over the `.Rows` collection) - you'll have to check the className for each td to find the one you want.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply @Tim Williams.. I'm not sure how to assign the Frame object correctly. I tried the following:

    Set MyFrame = ie.document.frames(12)
    Set MyTable = MyFrame.document.Tables

However, I cannot assign MyTable to the MyFrame Tables reference. I don't think I'm doing this correctly. 

Also I can see all of the data I need by using: 
    ie.document.frames(12).document.documentelement.innertext

But I can't seem to reference the Table correctly to loop or select the "TD" tags. Thanks again for looking

Comment: `document.tables` returns a collection of table objects, not a single table, so you'd need something like `set myTable=ie.document.frames(12).document.tables(1)` depending on exactly how many tables there are and which one you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I tried this but I received a 438 Error.. I tried using different table numbers starting from 0, and also tried using myTable=ie.document.frames(12).Tables(1) without success. I will edit the post again and include a bigger code snippet of the HTML I extracted with some comments shortly.. Thanks heaps for your advice

Answer (score 1):

How many tables are there in that frame?

Try something like:

```
Set HTMLDoc = ie.document.frames(12).document
Set tbls = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("table")

For x = 0 to tbls.length - 1  
    Set tbl = tbls(x)
    debug.print "Table# " & (x+1), "rows=" & tbl.Rows.length
Next x
```

Comment: There were several tables. Thanks very much I have solved the problem by checking the row length before validating. This saved me a lot of troubleshooting.