# Can I web scrape for a particular style in VBA?

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I have been looking everywhere for any possible workaround to this issue.

All of the data at my company is accessed via a web portal that produces static HTML pages. Unfortunately our department cannot be given direct access to the Server which would make my life easy so I need to page scrape this portal to find the data that I need. My navigation is fine and i am quite experienced with scraping where elements are named or given an ID, however this does not have either.

Anyway, background out of the way.

I want to grab a table from the page that has a unique style of "empty-cells: show;":

```
<TABLE  cellspacing=10 cellPadding=10 border="1" style="empty-cells: show;">

</TABLE>
```

Or failing that there is a heading in the first row which always contains the same text string. Once I have that table I can manipulate the data I need from it. Hugely sensitive data here guys, so I can't provide the full page code unfortunately.

I know that there have been many posts regarding GetElementByRegex but I cannot find a post or website that actually explains how to use it. Instead they all want me to install their add-on which isn't an option (I need to learn this to sate my thirst for knowledge).

To help I have added the full table code below removing the sensitive data:

```
<TABLE  cellspacing=10 cellPadding=10 border="0" width=100%>

<tr>

<td>
    <TABLE  cellspacing=10 cellPadding=10 border="1" style="empty-cells: show;">

                <TR class="row0">
                <TD style="width: 25%; background-color: #A3DCF5;"><strong>TITLE:</strong></TD>
                 <TD>LINE1</TD>
                </TR>
               <TR class="row1">
                    <TD>&nbsp;</TD><td>LINE2</td>
                </TR>
                <TR class="row0">
                    <TD>&nbsp;</TD><td>LINE3</td>
                </TR>
                <TR class="row1">
                    <TD>&nbsp;</TD><td>LINE4</td>
                </TR>
                <TR class="row0">
                    <TD>&nbsp;</TD><td>LINE5</td>
                </TR>

    </TABLE>
</td>

</tr>

</TABLE>
```

There are many other tables though so using a Len check will not help me top sift through the TD tags.

Comment: I had something (perhaps) similar once and I do a lot of trial and error and looped trough the tables collection (using `td` tag) and returned the table with thro amount of rows I wanted (that's when I knew I had the right table), then I tested to get the values in the row and column. I believe the sytnax would be `td.Rows(0).Cells(1).InnerText` for the first row and second column of the table. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26792344/loop-through-td-element-in-html-document-from-inside-frame-vba-excel-ie8-automat) isn't perfect, but it will give you a start.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this and see if I can work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim tbls, tbl, tr, j, td, row, sht

Set tbls = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("table")

For Each tbl in tbls
    'item indexes are zero-based (AFAIR)
    If tbl.Rows(0).Cells(1).innerText = "LINE1" Then


        'EDIT: extracting the table contents
        Set sht = ActiveSheet
        row = 3
        For Each tr In t.getelementsbytagname("TR")
            j = 1
            For Each td In tr.getelementsbytagname("TD")
                sht.Cells(row + 1, j).Value = td.innerText
                j = j + 1
            Next
            row = row + 1
        Next

        Exit For 'stop looping
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you, was very busy today due to Bank Holiday weekend, but I will take a look at this tomorrow.

Comment: This has worked to locate the table so thank you for the help, I just can;t work out how to copy the actual table data?

Comment: Worked it out now, thanks, answer edited into original question! You're a star, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Glitch_Doctor edited out of question:

Thank you for all the help Tim!

The below worked perfectly for me:

```
Dim tbls, tbl
Dim L1, L2, L3, L4, L5 As String

Set tbls = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("table")

For Each tbl In tbls
    If tbl.Rows(0).Cells(0).innerText = "Card Address:" Then

        On Error Resume Next
        L1 = tbl.Rows(0).Cells(1).innerText
        L2 = tbl.Rows(1).Cells(1).innerText
        L3 = tbl.Rows(2).Cells(1).innerText
        L4 = tbl.Rows(3).Cells(1).innerText
        L5 = tbl.Rows(4).Cells(1).innerText

        Exit For
    End If
Next

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = L1
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value = L2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Value = L3
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").Value = L4
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Value = L5

End Sub
```

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor If you wish to post this as your own answer (as an answer) leave a note and this can be deleted.

Comment: Thanks @QHarr , I might take a look at all my old questions as this was early days for me so I could be a re-offender... I have no need to post it myself for this Q&A

Comment: @Glitch_Doctor Thanks for letting me know.